# Adding the 'node' environment to my .eslintrc has unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm running eslint v1.8.0 against this `test.js` file:

```
require('fs');
var a = 1;
```

At first, my `.eslintrc` file is blank:

```
{
}
```

Running `eslint test.js` returns:

```
1:1  error  "require" is not defined       no-undef
1:9  error  Strings must use doublequote   quotes
2:5  error  "a" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

This is a node app, though, so I need to tweak it a bit. Running `eslint --env node test.js` returns:

```
1:9  error  Strings must use doublequote   quotes
2:5  error  "a" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Perfect, that's exactly what I want. So I modify my `.eslintrc` file to be:

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true
    }
}
```

When I run `estlint test.js` file now, it returns nothing at all. Why does adding this to my `.eslintrc` remove the `quotes` and `no-unused-vars` warnings?

Comment: After eslint 1.0.0, all the rules by default are off. So if you run eslint with no rules on you should get 0 results. This tells me that you might have `.eslintrc` file some where in the folder chain up or down which is getting picked up. Run eslint with `--debug` flag to understand where are the settings getting picked from.

Comment: Thanks! If you'll make that an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After eslint 1.0.0, all the rules by default are off. So if you run eslint with no rules on you should get 0 results. This tells me that you might have .eslintrc file some where in the folder chain up or down which is getting picked up. Run eslint with --debug flag to understand where are the settings getting picked from.